# "Show Taps" option is not working on LDPlayer?

Tags: android-emulator

I am using Android Emulator (LDPlayer 4.0.23).

The "**Show Taps**" option from Developer Options (**Setting-> Developer Options-> Show Taps**), doesn't work. It's activated/ON.

Normally when it's activated you will see simple transparent circle when you tap your screen. But it doesn't show in LDPlayer.

Anyone know how to make it work? Or is there any other apps that can be use as replacement?

FYI, I want to create some video tutorial, thus I need to show where I taps on it.

Answer (score 1):

you can try [NoxPlayer] (also an Android Emulator)to show taps and meet your needs. Here is a guide:
First, click **Setting** in the tool
[image: Setting]
Second, click **About tablet** and slide the page to find the **Build Number**
[2](https://www.bignox.com/) [image: Guiding picture]
Third, Tap the **Build Number** 7 times to open the developer option
[image: Build Number]
Fourth, Open the developer option, and then open the **Show Touch**
[image]